# Break away from the cycle and be made free

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Today is pain, and it has always been.
> Run with passion, there lies our sin.
>
> Unless forsaken, miserable we'll be.
> Taught the path, then freed are we.
>
> Here lies the freedom we all seek.

What am I?

Hint (I hope this doesn't make it too obvious)

> I am part of a philosophy or religion,
> I am taught so that you can leave your prison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is

> The Four Noble Truths

Today is pain, and it has always been.

> idam dukkham, "this is pain"

Run with passion, there lies our sin.

> ayam dukkha-samudayo, "this is the origin of pain"

Unless forsaken, miserable we'll be.

> ayam dukkha-nirodha, "this is the cessation of pain"

Taught the path, then freed are we.

> ayam dukkha-nirodha-gamini patipada, "this is the path leading to the cessation of pain."

Here lies the freedom we all seek.

> The cessation of the kleshas (afflictions) and the attainment of nirvana

The explanations come from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism recommended by OP in a comment to my other answer, great read!

Comment: This is a great answer, and I suppose it's partly correct (specifically the third line). But it's not the answer I'm looking for. I would try answering each line individually to come up with the answer.

Comment: Changed the answer again, hopefully to something that makes more sense, awesome and educational puzzle

Comment: Good job! I was worried that it was a little too general, though I thought I gave it away with my hint.

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> Truth?

Today is pain, and it has always been.
Run with passion, there lies our sin.

> I can be hard to tell the truth, but sometimes we may lie to get out of it.

Unless forsaken, miserable we'll be.
Taught the path, then freed are we.

> We need to get the truth off of our chest, and we are taught to do that.

Here lies the freedom we all seek.

> But we know e should tell the truth.

Also

> The first letter of each line spells truth.

Comment: Not quite, but you're on the right track. I'll say this, your answer is incomplete, though partly true.

Comment: Edit @Joe-You-Know

Comment: Your first answer was much closer to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> **ADDICTION** ?

Today is pain, and it has always been.
Run with passion, there lies our sin.

> Cravings of an addiction can be likened to pain.
>  Addiction is usually driven by emotional (and not rational) reasoning.

Unless forsaken, miserable we'll be.
Taught the path, then freed are we.

> Until you kick the habit, one continues to spiral downwards.
>  Once set on the path to an addiction-free life (e.g. AA), one is freed from its clutches.

Here lies the freedom we all seek.

> Addicts often (in their lucid moments) long to be free, but do not have the support, means and strength to do so.

Title: Break away from the cycle and be made free

> Addicts often go through a cycle of attempting to give it up, succumbing to temptation, rinse and repeat. To break away from this destructive cycle is what sets one free.

Comment: No, this isn't the answer I'm looking for. Your answer isn't on the right track to what I'm looking for. I will say, I do like this answer though.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I do agree that @QuantumTwinkie 's answer seems more appropriate, especially with his/her observation that ROT13(gur svefg yrggref bs rnpu yvar fcryy bhg GEHGU).

Answer (score 1):

The site suggested editing my answer instead of adding a new one so here goes:

How about

> Enlightenment/Nirvana

Title

> Break the cycle of reincarnation/karma

Today is pain, and it has always been.
Run with passion, there lies our sin.

> Attachment to possession and the longing for material things/money leads to suffering

Unless forsaken, miserable we'll be.
Taught the path, then freed are we.

> We must forsake our lusts and longing to follow the path of the Buddha to be free

Here lies the freedom we all seek.

> Free from human suffering

My old incorrect answer:

Is it

> Penance?

Today is pain, and it has always been.
Run with passion, there lies our sin.

> Wording is very much like religious dogma to resist temptations

Unless forsaken, miserable we'll be.
Taught the path, then freed are we.

> Temptation leads to suffering, unless we abstain

Here lies the freedom we all seek.

> Repentance (after Penance is complete) could be release from prison, perhaps

With respect to hints:

> Perhaps relates to heaven once we are freed in Christianity

Comment: This isn't the answer I'm looking for, but I really like the answer. You're heading in the right direction though.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know, is it perhaps rot13(pbasrffvba) or something related as  rot13(gehgu funyy frg lbh serr)?

Comment: No, but I like that idea a lot. Try to expand to other religions for the answer of this riddle.

Comment: Hopefully the new edit is more along the lines of the original puzzle

Comment: You're so close, but this isn't the answer that I'm looking for.

Comment: I think it has to do with rot13(zrqvgngvba) but other than than I don't know what to add

Comment: Not quite. You're so close. The answers to the clues are mostly correct (though I think each line deserves a separate explanation). You may benefit from this, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism

Comment: In the future, absolutely feel free to post a new answer for every independent solution.